# Search for a string under src using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, git-stash

I basically wanted to search for some sql stored procs in the code. For Eg:

```
video.sf_get_video_topology , video.sf_get_vod_entitlements, video.sf_get_account_service_cd
```

etc.

There are a lot of files and folders under src. I basically wanted to search all of the files and retrieve where this could be referenced. Any pointers what commands i can use to achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is your friend.

You should look into the `-r` option to go recursively through directories, and the `-l` option to only list filenames and not emit the matching lines.

The syntax is `grep [args] [regex] file`

e.g.

```
grep -rl "video.sf_get_video_topology" src/*
```

`grep` and regex's can be pretty powerful but also easy to make mistakes with, so I'd advise reading up on the man page there.